# Purge cached data from Apache mod_cache

Tags: apache-2.4, cache, apache2, mod-cache

How to force purge cached response from Apache `mod_cache` (`mod_cache_disk`)?

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html